# Login PDO script gives an error of `Call to a member function blind_param() on boolean`

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this login code while I tried exactly what the tutorial said, yet it gave me this error :

> Call to a member function blind_param() on boolean

The code goes as:

```
<?php

include ('db.php'); 

$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ?"."AND password = ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->blind_param('ss',$_POST['email'],$_POST['password']);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->blind_result($id);

if($stmt->fetch())
{
    echo 'loggin in';
} else {
    echo 'try again';
}
```

Any Help is Greatly Appreciated..

Comment: look like you do not read documentation properly ...! its Bind Not Blind

Comment: this is a typo question. no need for an answer. flagged as such :P

Answer (score 2):

```
$stmt -> bindParam(1,$_POST['email']);
$stmt -> bindParam(2,$_POST['password']);
```

For a prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the 1-indexed position of the parameter.
see:http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 1):

You query missing a space between `?` and `AND` :

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ? "."AND password = ?";
```

So, `$conn->prepare($sql);` fails and `$stmt` is false.

You should *ever* test the results of the functions :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if (!$stmt) { /* handle error */ }
else {
   $stmt->bind_param(...);
}
```

**NB:** PDO uses [`bindParam()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), MySQLi uses [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and [`bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php).

Comment: now it says `Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::blind_param()`

Comment: @HarishK As said @TarangP it's `bind_param()` not `blind_param` and `bind_result()` not `blind_result`.

Comment: @HarishK I've updated the answer with a note about PDO and MySQLi.